# AS3: Capturing compressed stream from microphone

Tags: actionscript-3

Now I have a code like this:

```
soundData = new ByteArray();
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
microphone.rate = 8;
microphone.gain = 100;
microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);

function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
  while (event.data.bytesAvailable) {
    var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
    soundData.writeFloat(sample);
  }
}
```

The raw data is recorded from the microphone. How do I go about casting it to a ByteArray after using SPEEX codec compression? Note that the converted data must play back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer a this code.

```
soundData.position=0;

var soundOutput:Sound = new Sound();
soundOutput.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playSound);
soundOutput.play();

function playSound(soundOutput:SampleDataEvent):void {
    if (! soundData.bytesAvailable>0)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) 
    {
        var sample:Number=0;
        if (soundData.bytesAvailable>0) 
        {
            sample=soundData.readFloat();
        }
        soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample);
        soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}
```

using a `SoundCodec.SPEEX` above code playrate not is 1x you should correct playSound function. maybe you tested. if you remove `microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;` know.

**More information**: [Adobe Official Capturing sound input](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html)

have a some problem when recorded in speex.

refer a follow artice.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3571251#3571251

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3584747

If the SoundFormat indicates Speex, the audio is compressed mono sampled at 16 kHz. In flash, a sound object plays at 44khz. Since you're sampling at 16khz(Speex), you're sending data through the SampleDataEvent Event handler 2.75 faster then you are getting that data. 
so, you must changed the playSound for(or while) loop.

I recommend following site. this article is 'how to playrate adjust?' great tutorial.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/